# Create docker swarm overlay network over a set of external and internal hosts

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Currently, I'm trying to create a docker swarm network over hosts. We have two different network sites, and one is a closed and private network. In this closed site, there is only one public IP assigned to us and hosts in this site have private IP addresses. Hosts in another network site have own public IP address to each host so there is no problem.

What I want to do is connecting hosts in the closed network site (called internal hosts) and hosts that have their own public IP addresses (called external hosts).

[image]

Because the only one public IP assigned to us for the closed network site, I set this public IP designated one internal host in the closed network site and this host became the docker swarm manager. Then, internal hosts joined to the swarm network using the internal IP address of the swarm manager host and external hosts joined using the public IP address.

For example, in the internal hosts:

```
docker swarm join --token ... 172.0.12.12:2377
```

and in the external hosts:

```
docker swarm join --token ... 123.123.123.123:2377
```

Joining was successfully done and I could recognize all nodes correctly in the swarm manager using `docker node ls` command. However, when I create an overlay network, this network is recognized in external hosts, but not in internal hosts. So, when I created a container in an external host and tried to ping from an internal host, it failed.

Is this a wrong way? Or is there anything that I should check? Any kind of ideas will be very helpful. Thanks!